# Сравнения разницы времени в Excel

Tags: excel, время

Пытаюсь сравнить время в Excel для вывода информации о "переработки" или "недоработки" в табеле, столкнулся с проблемой какой-то невиданной до этого.

Есть несколько ячеек:

1. Эталон часов A1 - "[ч]:мм" "8:00" (Подставленное значение из функции ВПР)
2. Фактически часов A2 - "[ч]:мм" "8:00" (Вычисленное значение из других 3х ячеек со временем `B2 (20:00) - B1 (11:00) - B3 (1:00)`, где форматы `B1,B2,B3 - "ч:мм"`)
3. Результат A3 - "[ч]:мм" Вычисляет переработку или недоработку путем разницы во времени по формуле:
   `=ЕСЛИ(([@[Фактически часов]]-[@[Эталон часов]])>0;"Переработка: "&ТЕКСТ([@[Фактически часов]]-[@[Эталон часов]];"[ч]:мм");ЕСЛИ(([@[Фактически часов]]-[@[Эталон часов]])=0;"Отработано";"Недоработка: "&ТЕКСТ([@[Эталон часов]]-[@[Фактически часов]];"[ч]:мм")))`

По факту имею то переработку, то недоработку в "0:00" часов. Не понимаю что делаю не так. Как-то по другому время нужно сравнивать?
заметил еще одну особенность: если сначала вычислить значение в отдельной ячейке, а потом ее сравнивать - то все работает нормально. Но если сразу написать в ячейке: `=A2-A1>0` то почему-то получается не 0.

upd: Вычислил и перевел значение `=ТЕКСТ(tbl_01[@[Фактически часов]]-tbl_01[@[Эталон часов]]; "0,00E+00")` в итоге имею число `1.11E-16`... Я конечно догадывался, что проблема какая-то в плавающих запятых. Но что делать-то? Как мне из 8 часов вычесть 8 часов и получить 0? :-(

Comment: >> *почему-то получается не 0... проблема какая-то в плавающих запятых* - именно. Что делать? Округлять до нужной точности

Comment: @vikttur как округлить время до нужной точности? ну например до минут?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибку дает  **стандарт вычислений IEEE 754** (стандарт двоичной арифметики с плавающей точкой (запятой)), применяемый в вычислительной технике. Не вдаваясь в подробности (об этом много доступной информации): ошибка возникает при арифметических операцях в 15 разряде после запятой.

Сутки - 1 (единица), время - часть суток:

`1 час - 1/24`; `1 минута - 1/(24*60) = 1/1440`; `1 секунда 1/(24*60*60) = 1/86400`

Т.к. время - число, то операции с ним тоже подвержены этой ошибке.

Обход ошибки - округление результата вычислений до нужной точности (а если есть промежуточные расчеты - то и их нужно округлять, чтобы не накапливалась ошибка).

Но какая точность для минут? Проверим.

В любую ячейку (например, `D2`) пишем формулу и протягиваем ее вниз на 59 строк:

```
=СТРОКА(A1)/1440
```

Получим значения минут (от 1 до 59) в формате времени.

Переведем формат ячеек в *Общий*. Явно видно, что для времени 9, 18, 27... минут число имеет 5 разрядов после запятой, в промежутках между этими минутами числа не имеют окончательной точности (0,...333...; 0,...667...; 0,...111...), т.е. с шестого разряда - бесконечное число (ну, бесконечным оно быть не может, т.к. в *Excel* ограничение вычислений - 15 значащих цифр, остальное преобразуется в нули).

Вот и имеем необходимую точность округления. Проверим.

В соседний столбец с нашими значениями пишем формулу округления (берем несколько разрядов с запасом) и тянем вниз:

```
=ОКРУГЛ(D2;9)
```

Получаем те же минуты, но с необходимой точностью, оставив ошибку в отрезаном хвосте.

С часами, так же, но можно брать 4-6 разрядов. Соответственно, для секунд количество разрядов больше. Хотя, 9-10 разрядов должны дать необходимую точность для любого времени.

Этот совет с округлением - только для обхода ошибки стандарта. Eсли из времени нужно извлекать отдельные составляющие (часы, минуты, секунды), то для этого в `Excel` есть соответствующие функции листа.